# T-SQL: how would you filter for 'ab,ab ab' but not 'ab, ab'?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Sorry if this question isn't clear.  The short story is that we had someone make some mistakes that resulted in a pretty nasty data corruption issue.  The end result is we ended up with a bunch of t-sql entries that look something to the effect of: 'value,value,value' and 'this, is a value,this is a value' with a couple thousand variations (and over 110k records impacted).

The problem is that we need to match items that contain a comma, anywhere in the string that is surrounded by any character (or lack thereof) except for a white space, by using SQL WHERE clauses.  As an example, I created some the following table of items, with a bit that indicates rather or not the given item should be returned by the query.

```
DECLARE @Ttests Table (  
  toMatch varchar(4000),
  shouldMatch bit
)
INSERT INTO @Ttests 
VALUES 
  ('value1,value2,value3,value1,value2,value3', 1),
  ('value1, value2, value3', 0),  
  (',value1, value2, value3', 1),  --starts with a comma
  ('value1, value2,value2', 1),
  ('this, is a sentence,this, is a sentence', 1),
  ('value1, value2, value3,', 1),  -- ends in a comma
  ('value1 ,value2, value3', 0);
```

The closest I seem to be able to get tonight is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
 *  
FROM @Ttests
WHERE PatIndex('[^ ]%,[^ ]%', toMatch) > 0
   OR PatIndex(',%', toMatch) > 0
   OR PatIndex('%,', toMatch) > 0
```

However, it returns a false match on the last item.  Any ideas?

Comment: Searching denormalized data, YUCK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have your '%' and '[^ ]' switched around the wrong way in your first `PatIndex`:

```
SELECT
 *  
FROM @Ttests
WHERE PatIndex('%[^ ],[^ ]%', toMatch) > 0
   OR PatIndex(',%', toMatch) > 0
   OR PatIndex('%,', toMatch) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, the sad part is I had that variation in there previously, but was trying to solve it without the two extra PatIndex matches, so had ended up changing it around.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *  
FROM @Ttests
WHERE
(
    toMatch LIKE '%[^ ],[^ ]%'
    OR toMatch LIKE ',[^ ]%'
    OR toMatch  LIKE '%[^ ],'
)
```

**OR** almost the same:

```
SELECT *  
FROM @Ttests
WHERE 
    PatIndex('%[^ ],[^ ]%', toMatch) > 0
OR  PatIndex(',[^ ]%', toMatch) > 0
OR  PatIndex('%[^ ],', toMatch) > 0
```